# Android strange error reported on the onPreExecute method

Tags: java, android, exception, android-asynctask

Today my G. Analytics account reports me an error on this line of code

```
private class GetSubscriptionListTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    boolean onlyUnread=true;

    public GetSubscriptionListTask(boolean onlyUnread) {
        super();
        this.onlyUnread=onlyUnread;
    }

    ProgressDialog progress;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
          //Show progress Dialog here
          super.onPreExecute();

          // create ProgressDialog here ...
          progress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity()); // <-- That's the line
          progress.setMessage("Downloading Subscriptions");
          // set other progressbar attributes

          progress.setCancelable (false);
          progress.setIndeterminate (true);
          progress.show();

    }
}
```

This is the line

```
progress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity()); // <-- That's the line
```

and this is the error report

```
NullPointerException (@SubscriptionsListFragment$GetSubscriptionListTask:onPreExecute:415) {main}
```

what does it mean? The nullexception is about the ProgressDialog or the getActivity()?

*UPDATE****
This error happens only one time on over 100 sessions.

Comment: you better initialize your progressbar in the `**oncreate**` method and you can also change `getActivity()` by `YouCLassName.this`

Comment: This error happens only one time on over 100 sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `getActivity()` if your class extends the `FragmentActivity`. else you try the `yourActivty.this` if your Class extends Activity

or you get the Activty reference in Fragment class call onAttach

```
Activity mActivity=null
@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        mActivity = activity;
    }
```

Comment: change with FragmentActivity

Comment: why that? I have a SubscriptionsListActivity that extends FragmentActivity that contains mine SubscriptionsListFragment that extends Fragment. Why I must change also theSubscriptionsListFragment to extends FragmentActivity??

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, Fragments are detached from your activity and getActivity() returns null.

You can see this here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

> Caution: If you need a Context object within your Fragment, you can
>   call getActivity(). However, be careful to call getActivity() only
>   when the fragment is attached to an activity. When the fragment is not
>   yet attached, or was detached during the end of its lifecycle,
>   getActivity() will return null.

That's why you get a NPE here.

Comment: Thank you! great explanation. Now I understand. But how can I solve this problem? What can I pass to the progress dialog instead of getActivity()?

Comment: If you execute your task at the creation of your fragment, move it to the onAttached method. Otherwise, your fragment is not displayed anymore, so you don't need to display your dialog and only need to check if getActivity() is not null before.

Comment: so you think that 
if(getActivity()!=null)
progress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());

could be a solution?

Comment: Yes, but only if you are not executing your task at the creation of your fragment

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way
private class GetSubscriptionListTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        boolean onlyUnread=true;
        Context context;

        public GetSubscriptionListTask(boolean onlyUnread,Context context) {
            super();
            this.onlyUnread=onlyUnread;
            this.context=context;
        }

        ProgressDialog progress;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //Show progress Dialog here
            super.onPreExecute();

            // create ProgressDialog here ...
            progress = new ProgressDialog(context); <-- That's the line
            progress.setMessage("Downloading Subscriptions");
            // set other progressbar attributes

            progress.setCancelable (false);
            progress.setIndeterminate (true);
            progress.show();

        }
```